# Wkhtmltopdf - set footer font's staff

Tags: php, linux, wkhtmltopdf

I use Wkhtmltopdf to generate pdf. Everything is good even with special font include by @font-face in CSS. Same method but don't influences footer font. Even --footer-font-name "Myriad Pro" or --footer-font-size 8 will not be performed. Footer's font is always serif and in default size.

My code:

```
'/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf --footer-html footer.html --footer-font-size 8 --footer-font-name "Myriad Pro" 1.html 1.pdf'
```

Somebody knows?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you use `--footer-html`, all the styling (including font-family and font-size) should be contained within the CSS in the file you specify.

`--footer-font-size` and `--footer-font-name` are only used with `--footer-left`, `--footer-center` and `--footer right`.